# How to open a URL in chrome incognito mode

Tags: c#, google-chrome, command-line

I set Chrome as default brower. To open a URL in Chrome, I wrote:

```
Process.Start("http://domain.com");
```

Is any way to open that URL in incognito mode by c# (nomarly press Ctrl + Shift + N)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You'll need to create a process with a path to Chrome's exe file, and use the argument `--incognito`.

The path to chrome in windows is typically:

`C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\chrome.exe`

Use the following code:

```
var url = "http://www.google.com";

using (var process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\chrome.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = url + " --incognito";

    process.Start();
}
```

An article explaining this: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/3479/google-chrome-use-a-command-line-switch-to-open-in-incognito-mode/

The full chrome command-line switch directory: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: I tried that way: 
            Process.Start(@"C:\Users\TUYEN\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe","--incognito --http://domain.com"); but it only open incognito mode but not access the URL

Comment: I have updated the answer so that it goes to the url that you provide.

Answer (score 9):

I wrote this and it successfull:

```
Process.Start(@"chrome.exe", "--incognito http://domain.com");
```

Comment: You need to dispose the object or you'll have a memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

The path to chrome.exe has changed, or at least i think there is a different between x32 and x64.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using the Brave browser, the solution is very similar to Dan's answer, just with the brave.exe path (note that for Brave, the exe is not located in `%LocalAppData%`).

```cs
var url = "http://www.google.com";

using (var process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = url + " --incognito";

    process.Start();
}
```