# How to dispose of processes after creating them?

Tags: c#, process, idisposable, process.start

To quote [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11857384/240733) to the question "[How to open a URL in chrome incognito mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857123/how-to-open-a-url-in-chrome-incognito-mode)":

> *I wrote this and it successfull:*
>
> ```
> Process.Start(@"chrome.exe", "--incognito http://domain.com");
> ```

someone replied with [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857123/how-to-open-a-url-in-chrome-incognito-mode#comment22730091_11857384):

> *You need to dispose the object or you'll have a memory leak.*

I generally create many processes with `Process.Start` but I never "dispose" of them. What is this and how do I do it?

Comment: try **.Close()** to close application.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185314/what-happens-if-i-dont-close-a-system-diagnostics-process-in-my-c-sharp-console. Your question gets answered there.

Comment: @Mohamadshiralizadeh `.Close()` does **NOT** close the application - it merely releases resources associated with it.

Comment: your right @Michael...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the Component article on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component(v=vs.110).aspx), that is correct. You should dispose of your `Process` object after use, releasing any unmanaged resources (the application will not close).

> A Component should release resources explicitly by calls to its Dispose method, without waiting for automatic memory management through an implicit call to the Finalize method. When a Container is disposed, all components within the Container are also disposed.

And from the `Process` [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This type implements the IDisposable interface. When you have finished using the type, you should dispose of it either directly or indirectly. To dispose of the type directly, call its Dispose method in a try/catch block. To dispose of it indirectly, use a language construct such as using (in C#) or Using (in Visual Basic). For more information, see the “Using an Object that Implements IDisposable” section in the IDisposable interface topic.

`Process` derives from `Component`, so you should dispose it. Its easy enough:

```
Process myProc = Process.Start(@"chrome.exe", "--incognito http://domain.com");
myProc.Dispose();
```

or even easier

```
using (Process myProc = Process.Start(@"chrome.exe", "--incognito http://domain.com"))
{
   //Do whatever with the process
}
```

The using block will dispose the object when the block is exited.

Comment: When you say dispose the object when the block is exited. The word dispose, does this mean the process is going to terminate? So if i load chrome + a website, then dispose it, is chrome now closed?

Comment: @ModS No, you are just releasing your un-managed handle to the process. The application will run normally.

Comment: @RandomUser I'm not sure what information you are referring to. The article on `Close` says `Dispose` calls it. They are still different method calls. I would *always* go the `Dispose` route, as it could do more than just call `Close`

Answer (score 0):

use `Process.Close();`

```
var Pro = new Process();
Pro.Start(@"chrome.exe", "--incognito http://domain.com");
Pro.WaitForExit(); //optional
Pro.Close();
```

Comment: Use `WaitForExit` with caution here; the thread will block until the application exits or `Close`/`Dispose` is called on another thread.

Comment: If i have a method that is doing this over and over, (example each time i click chrome it creates chrome's process) is it safe to globally declare Pro to avoid having to use the new keyword? and instead just re-assigning it over and over instead of creating it over and over?

Comment: @ModS That would guarantee a leak until the GC comes and finalizes the orphaned references. You should call `Dispose` (or `Close`) before reassignment

Comment: In theory: 
Globally declare Process Proc.
Use assign start info to Proc. Dispose Proc. Re-use as needed?
Will this still have a leak since i am disposing of all uses?

Comment: @ModS That version would be fine. Even easier would be to use a `using` block (variable creation is cheap!) but what you have would work.